# How to support Windows 8 & 8.1 Geolocation API

Tags: c#, .net, windows-store-apps

I've added Geolocation support to my program but I have a problem that I'm not sure how to handle.  I'm using VS 2012.

I've added a DLL to my solution which makes all of the Geolocation calls.  I set the version of Windows supported to 8.1 in the .csproj file.  The DLL project also uses .NET 4.5, while the rest of the projects in the solution use .NET 4.0.

I've got the following code in the method that retrieves the position:

```
protected override void Initialize() {
    // Initialization code here

    ParseGeoposition();  // Exception is thrown on this line
}

private void ParseGeoPositin() { 
    // . . .

    bool done = false;
    while ( !done )
        try {
            if ( UseCoordinate ) {
                newPosition.Position.Latitude  = positionRecord.Coordinate.Latitude;
                newPosition.Position.Longitude = positionRecord.Coordinate.Longitude;
            } else {
                newPosition.Position.Latitude  = positionRecord.Coordinate.Point.Position.Latitude;
                newPosition.Position.Longitude = positionRecord.Coordinate.Point.Position.Longitude;
            }
            done = true;
        } catch ( MissingMethodException ) {
            if ( !UseCoordinate ) {
                throw new NotSupportedException( "This machine does not support the Windows Geolocation API." );
            }
            UseCoordinate = false;
        }
    // . . .
}
```

The `UseCoordinate` flag starts out `true`.  The code is supposed to switch to using the `Point` property (by setting `UseCoordinate` to `false` If the `Coordinate` property is not supported.

The code runs fine on my Windows 8.1 development machine.  But, when I install it on a Windows 8.0 machine, A `MissingMethodException` is being thrown on the line that calls the method that has this code in it.  It's as though the try isn't there.  The exception that is thrown reads:

> System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Windows.Devices.Geolocation.Geopoint Windows.Devices.Geolocation.Geocoordinate.get_Point()'.

Obviously my approach is flawed. I'd prefer not to look at the Windows version number as my manager does not want me to.  What's the right way to code this

Comment: This is a desktop application, not a windows store app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception is happening, when the method is being compiled by the JITer - you either need to use 8.0 compatible geo-location API calls ([`Geolocator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.geolocation.geolocator.aspx) and friends), or guard calls to the methods that use 8.1 specific instructions with the appropriate `try ... catch` blocks.

Comment: I'm giving you the credit but I'm going to add another answer to outline what I did.  It's too long for a comment.

Comment: BTW, `GeoCoordinateWatcher` is a Windows 7 API, not a Windows 8.0 API.

Comment: Good point, I'd copy pasted my abstraction name, rather than the underlying class, which works on Windows 8.0 (and later), which I've now added, with link to documentation

Answer (score 2):

Using information from Rowland, I was able to get this working.  The difference between the Windows 8 & Windows 8.1 APIs is in the `Geocoordinate` class's `Coordinate` property.  In Windows 8, the `Coordinate` property is a `Geocoordinate` object that has `Latitude`, `Longitude`, and `Altitude` properties.  In Windows 8.1, these properties still exist, but are marked obsolete.  The `Geocoordinate` class in Windows 8.1 has a new property called `Point` of type `Geopoint`.  This has a property called `Position` of type `BasicGeoposition`.  This object has the `Latitude`, `Longitude`, and `Altitude` properties.

There alread was a private instance variable in the class called `positionRecord`:

```
private Geoposition positionRecord = null;
```

This is set by calling `GetPositionAsync` in the `Initialize` method and then whenever the `Geolocator` raises its `PositionChanged` event.  I created two sets of functions in my code:

```
private double GetAltitudeFromCoordinate() {
    return positionRecord.Coordinate.Altitude == null ? 0.0 : positionRecord.Coordinate.Altitude.Value;
}

private double GetAltitudeFromPoint() {
    return positionRecord.Coordinate.Point.Position.Altitude;
}

private double GetLatitudeFromCoordinate() {
    return positionRecord.Coordinate.Latitude;
}

private double GetLatitudeFromPoint() {
    return positionRecord.Coordinate.Point.Position.Latitude;
}

private double GetLongitudeFromCoordinate() {
    return positionRecord.Coordinate.Longitude;
}

private double GetLongitudeFromPoint() {
    return positionRecord.Coordinate.Point.Position.Longitude;
}
```

Next, I created two methods that are called to parse the Latitude & Longitude:

```
private void ParseLatLonFromCoordinate( GpsInformation newPosition ) {
    // We assume this is a Windows 8.0 machine that doesn't have the Point property.
    newPosition.Position.Latitude  = positionRecord.Coordinate.Latitude;
    newPosition.Position.Longitude = positionRecord.Coordinate.Longitude;
}

private void ParseLatLonFromPoint( GpsInformation newPosition ) {
    // The system must not support the Coordinate.Latitude & Longitude properties any more.
    newPosition.Position.Latitude  = positionRecord.Coordinate.Point.Position.Latitude;
    newPosition.Position.Longitude = positionRecord.Coordinate.Point.Position.Longitude;
}
```

I added a `bool` property called `UseCoordinates` to the class.  In the program's initialization code, I added this line to initialize the flag:

```
UseCoordinate = positionRecord.Coordinate.GetType().GetProperty( "Point" ) == null;
```

Finally, I added a method called `ParsePosition` that is called after the above code and whenever the `Geolocator` raises the `PositionChanged` event:

```
private void ParsePosition() {
    GpsInformation newPosition = new GpsInformation();
    newPosition.TimeStamp = DateTime.Now;

    try {
        if ( UseCoordinate )
            ParseLatLonFromCoordinate( newPosition );
        else
            ParseLatLonFromPoint( newPosition );
    } catch ( MissingMethodException ) {
        // The Geolocation API must not be supported.
        throw new NotSupportedException( "This machine does not support the Windows Geolocation API." );
    }

    // . . .
}
```

This works on both Windows 8 & 8.1 without throwing `MissingMethodExceptions.`